# Program runs only with None results

Tags: python, python-requests

My problem is: my program runs only with None results. I guess there is a problem with the data parameters in my program.

```
from lxml import html
import requests    
etree = html.etree
class News(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url ='https://www.chinatimes.com/newspapers/260118'
        self.headers ={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"}

    def get_data(self,url):
        response =requests.get(url,headers=self.headers)
        return response.content

    def parse_data(self, data):
        # 创建 element对象
        data = data.decode()
        html = etree.HTML(data)
        el_list = html.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/ul/li/div/div/div/h3/a/font')
        data_list = []
        for el in el_list:
            temp = {}
            temp['title'] = el
            temp['link'] = 'https://www.chinatimes.com' + el.xpath("./@href")[0]
            data_list.append(temp)
         try:
            # 获取 下一页的url
            next_url = 'https://www.chinatimes.com' + html.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/nav/ul/li[7]/a/@href')[0]
        except:
            next_url = None
        return data_list, next_url

    def save_data(self, data_list):
        for data in data_list:
            print(data)

    def run(self):
        # url
        next_url = self.url
        while True:
            data = self.get_data(next_url)       
            data_list, next_url = self.parse_data(data)
            self.save_data(data_list)
            print(next_url)
            if next_url == None:
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
        news =News()
        news.run()
```

I use Google Chrome, and my XPATH should be correct. I think there is a problem with my data parameter, but I am not sure about it. I hope someone can help me see it. thank you very much. Because when the problem was submitted, the system always said that most of the files I submitted were code, so I can only make up some words, I hope I can submit them.

I thought about it again. It would be better to start from here. Maybe my position is correct, but I don't know how to solve the problem here: `data = data.decode()`

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: And can you provide a few examples of your desired output?

Comment: thank you very much ,the problem has been solved@Jack Fleeting